# MySql - is possible that performance issues are caused by dynamic SQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures, database-performance

We have this MySQL SP, which uses dynamic SQL.
It seems it does NOT perform well under load.

It is possible that this SP becomes slow under load because it uses dynamic SQL?
Can dynamic SQL cause performance issues in MySql (eg because it is not cached by the engine)?

Please note that this SP is called from several other SPs. It passes results to parent SPs using a temp table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `CreateAreas`(
    _areas varchar(21844),
    _comparisonGroup varchar(21844),
    _parentArea varchar(21844),
    _areaType varchar(21844)
)
BEGIN

    -- create temporary table "areas"
    -- fill with area ids

    create temporary table areas (
        id int not null,
        code varchar(30),
        name varchar(100),
        shortName varchar(100),
        levelid int not null,
        sortOrder int not null,
        key (id)
    );

    -- assumes that only one of the 3 options is valid, areas, comparison group, bounded comparison group

    if (_areas is not null) then

        set @sql = concat('insert into areas (id, code, name, shortName, levelid, sortOrder) select id, Code, Name, ShortName, LevelID, 0 from GeoArea where Code in (''', replace(_areas, ',', ''','''), ''')');
        prepare stmt from @sql;
        execute stmt;
        deallocate prepare stmt;

    elseif (_comparisonGroup is not null) then

        -- might not be the most efficient way, but is consistent with the approach above, and we do not expect the list to be long
        insert into areas (id, code, name, shortName, levelid, sortOrder)
        select GeoAreaID, GeoArea.Code, GeoArea.Name, GeoArea.ShortName, GeoArea.LevelID, SortOrder
        from ComparisonGroupGeoAreaLink
        INNER JOIN
        GeoArea
        ON GeoArea.ID = GeoAreaID
        where ComparisonGroupID = (select id from ComparisonGroup where Identifier = _comparisonGroup)
        and IsMember = 1;

    elseif (_parentArea is not null and _areaType is not null) then

        -- might not be the most efficient way, but is consistent with the approach above, and we do not expect the list to be long
        insert into areas (id, code, name, shortName, levelid, sortOrder)
    select a.ID, a.Code, a.Name, a.ShortName, a.LevelID, 0
        from (select id from GeoArea where Code = _parentArea) as t
        INNER JOIN
        GeoAreaLinkCache c
        ON
        c.ParentAreaID = t.id
        inner join GeoArea a
        on c.ChildAreaID = a.ID
        INNER JOIN
        (select id from GeoAreaLevel where Identifier = _areaType) as l
        ON
        a.LevelID = l.id;        

    elseif (_areaType is not null) then

        -- might not be the most efficient way, but is consistent with the approach above, and we do not expect the list to be long
        set @sql = concat('insert into areas (id, code, name, shortName, levelid, sortOrder)
        select a.ID, a.Code, a.Name, a.ShortName, a.LevelID, 0
        from 
        (select id from GeoAreaLevel where Identifier in (''', replace(_areaType, ',', ''','''), ''')) l
        INNER JOIN
        GeoArea a
        ON
        a.LevelID = l.id');
        prepare stmt from @sql;
        execute stmt;
        deallocate prepare stmt;


    end if;                 

END
```

Comment: Not a duplicate - this one is focused on dynamic Sql, not SP nesting

Answer (score 1):

Yes. An advantage to stored procedures is that they can be parsed, query plans can be cached, etc.

Dynamic SQL (or ad-hoc queries) have no such advantage.

That said, it is somewhat unlikely that your performance bottleneck comes from dynamic SQL, and more likely that it comes from lack of indexes, too many inserts/deletes, etc.

Comment: Please note that we use dynamic Sql in MySql SP

Comment: Further to this, the SP appears to use a couple of queries which use sub queries which do not appear to be necessary and which might well be preventing MySQL using indexes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems dynamic SQL is NOT a bottleneck.

I've changed temp tables to MEMORY engine and it really did the trick and made AMAZING difference. Solution was suggested in

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/can-mysql-nested-sp-be-a-bottleneck/52863?noredirect=1#52863

```
create temporary table areas (
    id int not null,
    code varchar(30),
    name varchar(100),
    shortName varchar(100),
    levelid int not null,
    sortOrder int not null,
    key (id)
) ENGINE=MEMORY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a play to remove the sub queries from the inserts (not tested). Might be worth trying doing an EXPLAIN of these queries (well, the SELECT parts) and comparing them to EXPLAINS of the ones from the original SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `CreateAreas`(
    _areas varchar(21844),
    _comparisonGroup varchar(21844),
    _parentArea varchar(21844),
    _areaType varchar(21844)
)
BEGIN

    -- create temporary table "areas"
    -- fill with area ids

    create temporary table areas (
        id int not null,
        code varchar(30),
        name varchar(100),
        shortName varchar(100),
        levelid int not null,
        sortOrder int not null,
        key (id)
    );

    -- assumes that only one of the 3 options is valid, areas, comparison group, bounded comparison group

    if (_areas is not null) then

        set @sql = concat('insert into areas (id, code, name, shortName, levelid, sortOrder) 
                            select id, Code, Name, ShortName, LevelID, 0 
                            from GeoArea 
                            where Code in (''', replace(_areas, ',', ''','''), ''')');
        prepare stmt from @sql;
        execute stmt;
        deallocate prepare stmt;

    elseif (_comparisonGroup is not null) then

        -- might not be the most efficient way, but is consistent with the approach above, and we do not expect the list to be long
        insert into areas (id, code, name, shortName, levelid, sortOrder)
        select GeoAreaID, GeoArea.Code, GeoArea.Name, GeoArea.ShortName, GeoArea.LevelID, SortOrder
        from ComparisonGroupGeoAreaLink
        INNER JOIN GeoArea
        ON GeoArea.ID = GeoAreaID
        INNER JOIN ComparisonGroup
        ON ComparisonGroupID = ComparisonGroup.id
        WHERE ComparisonGroup.Identifier = _comparisonGroup
        AND IsMember = 1;

    elseif (_parentArea is not null and _areaType is not null) then

        -- might not be the most efficient way, but is consistent with the approach above, and we do not expect the list to be long
        insert into areas (id, code, name, shortName, levelid, sortOrder)
    select a.ID, a.Code, a.Name, a.ShortName, a.LevelID, 0
        from GeoArea t
        INNER JOIN GeoAreaLinkCache c
        ON c.ParentAreaID = t.id
        inner join GeoArea a
        on c.ChildAreaID = a.ID
        INNER JOIN GeoAreaLevel l
        ON a.LevelID = l.id
        where l.Identifier = _areaType
        AND Code = _parentArea;        

    elseif (_areaType is not null) then

        -- might not be the most efficient way, but is consistent with the approach above, and we do not expect the list to be long
        set @sql = concat('insert into areas (id, code, name, shortName, levelid, sortOrder)
        select a.ID, a.Code, a.Name, a.ShortName, a.LevelID, 0
        from GeoAreaLevel l
        INNER JOIN GeoArea a
        ON a.LevelID = l.id
        where l.Identifier in (''', replace(_areaType, ',', ''','''), ''')');
        prepare stmt from @sql;
        execute stmt;
        deallocate prepare stmt;


    end if;                 

END
```